# Gray line below status bar when presenting activity

Tags: android, android-activity, statusbar

For some reason a gray line appears below the status bar when a basic activity is presented.

Any idea why?

[image]

Comment: Likely a "shadow" or something automatically created by android materials design to give the app more depth

Comment: D'you think?, Happens I don't have the line the in my main activity... it only happens when I start a new activity

Comment: Does it only happen if the activity is blank? If you make the background a solid color does it still happen?